# Ant media server invalidate token while fetching VOD chunks

Tags: unauthorized, ant-media-server-sdk

I have the ant media server VOD embedded on a different domain. While playing the stream it works fine for the first chunk request, but as soon as you click anywhere on the seek bar and it tries to fetch the required chunk, the one-time token invalidates.
There is a case conflict that I'm not able to understand.

1. If I play the stream directly in the browser, it works fine every time, which means it is a valid token and works when you request chunks from anywhere in the stream.
2. If I set the publish token to false in settings, everything works fine in the embedded page, which means it is not a Cors issue as well.

I'm wondering what could be the issue that can lead to such kind of conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to play with a non-https page? Ant Media Server one-time token system checks session IDs. If you trying to play with a non-https page, each request can get a different session ID. You need to use HTTPS in your system. Could you please try with HTTPS page?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it is already an HTTPS page.

Comment: Could you please make sure HTTP request session IDs are same?

Comment: Yes, you're right somehow cookies are not getting saved in the browsers while I embed the VOD.